# If else logic depending on several rows

Tags: php

On my site I have page where rows are generated using below code:

```
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    if($row['type']=='1'){ $tipo="one";}
    if($row['type']=='2'){ $tipo="two";}
    if($row['type']=='3'){ $tipo="three";}
    if($row['type']=='4'){ $tipo="four";}
    if($row['type']=='5'){ $tipo="five";}
    if($row['type']=='6'){ $tipo="six";}
    if($row['type']=='7'){ $tipo="seven";}
    if($row['type']=='8'){ $tipo="eight";}
    if($row['type']=='9'){ $tipo="nine";}
    if($row['type']=='10'){ $tipo="ten";}
?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php
    if($row['type']=='9') {
        echo 'Text One';
    }
    else { 
        echo 'Text two';
    } ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<?php
}
?>
```

**After this I need a code which will do next thing:**

If there is one row and  `$row['type']=='9'` than echo text "nine", if there is one row and `$row['type']!=='9'`echo text "not nine", but if there are several rows and if for at least one of them `$row['type']=='9'` echo text "both" else echo "non of them"

I can't figure it out how to do this. Could you help me a little?

Comment: You have your answer in your question... your explanation of what you want just has to be reworded in PHP. Using pseudo-code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) could help you formalize what you want and how to code it.
If you still struggle with that, add your code and we'll be able to able you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flag variable for what you want

Try something like this:

```
<?php

    $row_cnt=0;
    $type_9=false;

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

    if($row['type']=='1'){ $tipo="one";}
    if($row['type']=='2'){ $tipo="two";}
    if($row['type']=='3'){ $tipo="three";}
    if($row['type']=='4'){ $tipo="four";}
    if($row['type']=='5'){ $tipo="five";}
    if($row['type']=='6'){ $tipo="six";}
    if($row['type']=='7'){ $tipo="seven";}
    if($row['type']=='8'){ $tipo="eight";}
    if($row['type']=='9'){ $tipo="nine";}
    if($row['type']=='10'){ $tipo="ten";}
    $rowcnt++;
    ?>



    <?php
    if($row['type']=='9') {    
        $type_9=true;
    }
    ?>



    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <tbody><tr><td>
    <?php 
    if($row_cnt == 1)
    {
      if($type_9)
        echo "nine";
      else
        echo "not nine";
    }
    else if($rowcnt > 1)
    {
      if($type_9)
        echo "both";
      else
        echo "non of them";
    }

    ?>
    </td></tr></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have omitted the HTML-tags but I think you can add those easily.

```
$tipo = array();
$multiple = false;
$present = false;
$numbers = array ( 
             '1' => "one",
             '2' => "two",
             '3' => "three",
             '4' => "four",
             '5' => "five",
             '6' => "six",
             '7' => "seven",
             '8' => "eight",
             '9' => "nine",
             '10' => "ten",
         );

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ) 
      $tipo[] = $numbers[ $row['type'] ]; 

$multiple = (count($tipo) > 1 ) ? true : false;
$present = ( in_array('9', $tipo) ) ? true : false;

if( $multiple ) {
    if ( $present )
       echo 'both';
    else
       echo 'none of them';
} else {
    if ( $present )
       echo 'nine';
    else
       echo 'not nine';
}
```